# Use ".filter" in angular

Tags: angular, angular-http, angular5, angular-httpclient

I try filter data (get records with given number)

```
http.get(baseUrl + 'api/Student/Students1')
.filter( stud => stud.Phone == 123)
.subscribe(data => {
this.studentTEST = data.json() as Students[];
}, error => console.error(error));
```

But get error:

> " Property 'Phone' does not exist on type 'Response' ".

Version of angular was 4.2.5, but lately updated in package.json (5.1.0).
Find

I get db context from asp.net core controller.

This is my angular code:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'RxJS';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';


@Component({
    selector: 'fetchdata',
    templateUrl: './fetchdata.component.html'
})
export class FetchDataComponent {

    public studentTEST: Students[];
    public stud: Students[];

    constructor(private http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {

    http.get(baseUrl + 'api/Student/Students1')
    .map((response: Response) => response.json() as Students[])
    .filter(stud => stud.Phone === 123);
    //subscribe(result => {
        //this.studentTEST = result.json();
 }


}

export interface Students {
     StdName: string;
     Email: string;
     Phone: number;
     Address: string;
 }
```

Now error :

> Property 'Phone' does not exist on type 'Students[]'.

Comment: Please add some more details, response object or maybe even a working code example

Comment: add description

Comment: Everything would be much easier if you named things correctly. You have an array of Students instance. So each element of the array is a Students. What is a Students? A group of students? So your API returns groups of students? Or does it, as I imagine, return an array of students, and each object in the array is thus **one Student**? Note that the Http service is deprecated. You'd better learn how to use the HttpClient service instead.

Comment: Hey! Did any answer help you? :)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to `map` your get request to json() or use `httpClient`. Then you can filter, and remove you subscribe method from service. You need to subscribe in component you can use `| async` pipe.

`http.get(baseUrl + 'api/Student/Students1')
  .map((response: Response) => response.json() as Students[])
  .filter(stud => stud.Phone === 123);`

Comment: You must import Response from http, and map and filter from rxjs/add/operator/map and rxjs/add/operator/filter.Please post your code so we can find those errors.

Comment: How else i can get the necessary data?

Comment: You need to write service and create method remove code from constructor. 
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4. Then we can inject service in your component, and call method and subscribe to get data. Also we will use HttpClient https://angular.io/guide/http. Lets refactor your code.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If the json contains an array of Students, how could `stud.Phone` even compile? Arrays don't have a `Phone` property.

Answer (score 1):

The latter error is completely correct:

> `Property 'Phone' does not exist on type 'Students[]'`.

It doesn't. `Phone` exists on `Students`, not `Students[]`.

You actually need to set the `filter` in your map:

```
http.get(baseUrl + 'api/Student/Students1')
 .map(response => response.json().filter(stud => stud.Phone === 123))
```

Then what you return here, is no longer a response of type `Students[]` so you need to leave that out.